# password_reset does not pick from_email when using sendgrid

Tags: django, sendgrid, django-rest-auth

I have my email setup for entire django project and it works fine. When it comes to reset password in the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/password_reset/
```

and after submitting the email, it throws:

```
SMTPDataError at /rest-auth/password_reset/
(550, b'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved.
```

when I digged into the issue I noticed that this view doesn't catch from_email at all:

[image]

If I manually enter the email here, everything works fine. Also if I use gmail it works fine.

I am wondering what is gone wrong that email is not read!

Comment: You can either subclass the view to set the from_email or the best way would be to set the from email in the urls itself `PasswordResetView.as_view(from_email="example@example.com")`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug, but implemented intentionally in Django.
Django maintains a settings.py parameters termed [DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL), which is applied by default if the from_email you've mentioned is None (in EmailMessage class construction).
Note that the email itself is sent by the PasswordResetForm class (forms.py), and it will only be sent out if the receipt is an active user (implementedin the get_users function).